# What is a good way to make a link between two React components at different hierarchy levels?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-redux

I'm relatively new to React and I'm trying to figure out how I should compose a complex application (not just a simple TODO app).

I have basically a structure like this (greatly simplified):

```
<Application>
  <MenuBar />
  <Router>
    <Route path="/page1" component={Page1} />
    <Route path="/page2" component={Page2} />
    <Route path="/page3" component={Page3} />
  </Router>
</Application>
```

`<MenuBar>` is basically an [AppBar](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar), however **with the left icon *not* visible at all times**.

There will be many Page components (visible below the MenuBar) and a few of them will use a [Drawer](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/drawer) for varying reasons.

Depending on the available screen resolution I want my application to be responsive and either:

- use the [Drawer](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/drawer) component on small screens, or
- show a fixed sidebar on large screens (like the opened Drawer, but without covering the main content)

This screenshot makes it easier to understand, perhaps:
[image]

The content of the Drawer and the sidebar will be exactly the same, as only either one is visible.

Therefore, I'd like to create a `<DynamicDrawer>` component that can be used at the top level of any Page component:

```
render() {

  const selectionList = <div>will be visible in the drawer/sidebar</div>;
  const myContent = <div>will be the main content of the page</div>;

  return (
    <DynamicDrawer
      drawerContent={selectionList}
      mainContent={myContent}
    />
  );
}
```

I have no problem implementing that `<DynamicDrawer>`, however the `<MenuBar>` of the application component needs some connection to the active `<DynamicDrawer>`:

- when using the Drawer, the `<MenuBar>` must show the left icon, otherwise not
- when the user clicks/taps on that icon, the `<Drawer>` must be toggled

Should I use some store like Redux to solve this problem? Or pass handlers and state manually around? Should I redesign the component hierarchy completely?

Comment: why is your menubar outside of the router?

Comment: @JohnRuddell: good question.. I did it that way because the `MenuBar` is a component that is *always* visible, regardless of the route. It should, however, reflect the current route *internally* by highlighting an menu item (didn't concentrate on that yet). Since I'm still learing.. is there a better way to organize it, having the `MenuBar` inside the route? I don't think it would be a good idea to add the `MenuBar` to each routed sub-component..?

Comment: So are supposed to have the route render a main index component and that component will render everything it needs.. aka when the route is `/` you have an index route. it is usually called an `App` component and is the parent of everything.. so in `App` you would render the menu bar and then `{this.props.children}` the children are the other components that are supposed to be rendered based off of the route..

Answer (score 1):

React makes DOM manipulations very straightforward and alarmingly fast.
However, most of the changes on your DOM should be determined by data, and not manually manipulated by you (even if you have the power to). Break this rule and hell will let loose as your app begins to get increasingly complex.

So no, you shouldn't pass handlers and state manually around, and yes, you may very likely have to redesign the hierarchy (flow is a bit cut off from the `MenuBar`, almost like it's meant to be static).

I might not be able to say specifically what your new hierarchy should be. This is purely dependent on how you want data to flow.

Here's why React users love libraries like `Flux` and `Redux`. Both preach that data should only flow in one direction, and all state changes should only occur though a single dispatch call.

Since you're new to React, and have gotten a hang of the basics, I think it's time to look at `Redux`. Once you understand it, it will be clear to you where to place not just the `Menu bar`, but also any other component you wish to add.

**Edit 1**

Since you will love to manipulate the Menubar using the state of the top-level component, instead of just css rules, then the `<MenuBar />` component should be within the top-level component, and not with the Router (as a matter of fact, seeing the `<MenuBar />` with the router is very strange anyways :).

Your top-level component's `render()` could look like this:

```
render() {

  const selectionList = <div>will be visible in the drawer/sidebar</div>;
  const myContent = <div>will be the main content of the page</div>;

  return (
    <div>
      <Menubar />
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

While your `<DynamicDrawer />` stay the same. This way, you could pass callbacks as props and watch for changes in the `<DynamicDrawer />` that could be used to influence the visibility of the sidebar.

I'd have to add though. If it's only 'screen resolution' that affects the sidebar visibility, having css rules in place could be one way to go.

Comment: Yes, effectively, the MenuBar is somewhat static and always visible, I should have mentioned that. I also expected that it would be a good idea to use Redux, although with "pass handlers and state msnually around" I really meant the React way, by using props and callbacks. Still, I wonder why you suggest to change the component hierarchy. Can you explain please?

Comment: @UdoG Oh if the MenuBar is static and does not partake in, nor benefit from any data manipulations, then your current hierarchy looks fine. It's a good thing you've decided to use Redux. You'd enjoy it :)

Comment: Uhm.. with "static" I rather meant "fixed", or "always visible", regardless of the route. As described in the question, it *indirectly* depends on the "screen resolution" since it's left icon (`≡`) should only be visible when the `<DynamicDrawer>` is in Drawer mode (and not in sidebar mode). So, in some way the `<DynamicDrawer>` needs to influence the `<MenuBar>`. I'm confident this can be done using Redux, but is my hierarchy still designed wisely then?

Comment: With other words: *the ≡ icon of the `<MenuBar>` must be visible when there is a `<DynamicDrawer>` visible and it decides to hide it`s `drawerContent` behind a MaterialUI `<Drawer>`. When the user clicks on that ≡ icon inside the `<MenuBar>`, then the `<DynamicDrawer>` must toggle it`s `<Drawer>` child.*

Comment: I take it that `drawerMode` and `sideBarMode` are states of the `<DynamicDrawer />` Component. If this is the case, then yes, you can reach it using redux. However, to make the `<Menubar />` join other application component, you might need to put it in the component that's going to be served by `React-Router`. I will edit my answer shortly to reflect a possible way you could go about this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and your edit. Wouldn't that mean that the `<MenuBar>` gets re-initialized when switching routes since each page has it's own `<MenuBar>`? That would be bad since there are CSS transitions (showing the transition between routes) that probably won't work when the `<MenuBar>` gets replaced (by a similar looking, but new instance). -- assuming that with "top-level component" you still mean a component *within* a `<Route>`

Comment: @UdoG Yes, you're absolutely correct. I made a subtle edit to the answer to take on your specific case, assuming that the `Page1` component passed to `react-router` is a parent to `<DynamicDrawer />`. However, this is the right logical approach. Your routing component should be concerned with just that - routing. That's why the `<MenuBar />` didn't belong there (no matter how efficient that might feel like).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115127/discussion-between-udo-g-and-cent).

Answer (score 1):

By re-reading the [Router documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md) I noticed that `<Route>` can be nested *and* still each `<Route>` level can have it's own components.

That solves my problem in a very elegant way:

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/" component={AppOuter}>
    <Route path="/page1" component={Page1} />
    <Route path="/page2" component={Page2} />
    <Route path="/page3" component={Page3} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

...with my `MenuBar` being a child of `AppOuter`:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div> 
      <MenuBar />
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

That means that while being on `page1` this results into...

```
<AppOuter>
  <MenuBar />
  <Page1 />
</AppOuter>
```

That way I can keep my Page components and the permanent parts of my application (like the `MenuBar`) at the same level, i.e. `AppOuter` and `PageX` can receive the same props and I can pass callbacks to the page components which belong to the top level component (containing the Router).

Still, it's probably better to go with this hierarchy but use Redux (or similar) to manage the state.

...React is awesome ;-)

Comment: I see you went with what I recommended :) This is what react router is made for and its a ways of sharing components between pages in an elegant way :)